# How to use code to solve the parity periodic accumulation problem?

Tags: functions

Given that the function f(x) is an odd function with a domain of real numbers `R`, and it satisfies the condition `f(1-x) = f(1+x)`. If `f(1) = 2`, calculate the sum of `f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(50)`.

To solve this problem, we need to understand the properties of odd functions and use them to find a pattern in the values of f(x). An odd function has the property that f(-x) = -f(x), which means that the function is symmetrical around the origin.

Since f(1-x) = f(1+x), we can say that the function has a symmetry axis at x=1. This means that the values of the function are the same when x is increased or decreased by 2 units from 1.

Using these properties, we can find the values of f(x) for some specific points:

- f(1) = 2
- f(0) = f(2) (due to symmetry)
- f(-1) = f(3) (due to symmetry)
- f(-2) = f(4) (due to symmetry)
- ...

Since the function is an odd function, we know that f(0) = 0. Therefore, we can conclude that:

- f(0) = 0
- f(2) = 0
- f(3) = -2
- f(4) = 0
- ...

We can observe that the values of f(x) repeat every 4 units. Therefore, we can divide the range from 1 to 50 into 12 groups of 4 units each, and the sum of each group will be 0 (since the values within each group cancel each other out).

Hence, the sum of f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(50) will be equal to the sum of the first 12 groups plus the value of f(1), which is 2.

Therefore, the final answer is:

f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(50) = 12 * 0 + 2 = 2.

However, the following code did not solve this problem.

```
Clear["`*"]
f[x_] := -f[-x] /; x > 0; f[x_] := f[-x + 2] /; x <= 0; 
f[1] = 2 /; x = 1;
Sum[f[k], {k, 1, 50}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The recursion only stops for integer values of x, so the function is only defined for integers.

```
f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 2;
f[x_Integer?Negative] := f[x] = -f[-x];
f[x_Integer?Positive] := f[x] = f[2 - x];

Sum[f[k], {k, 1, 50}]

(* 2 *)
```

**EDIT:** To find a closed form,

```
seq = f /@ Range[20];

f2[x_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, x] //
  Simplify

(* Sin[(π x)/2] - Sin[(3 π x)/2] *)

And @@ Table[f[x] == f2[x], {x, -50, 50}]

(* True *)

Show[
 Plot[f2[x], {x, -10, 10}],
 DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]