How to find the cumulative value through the abstract function analytic expression?

Clear["`*"]
g[x_ /; x < 4] := g[8 - x]
g[4] = 8
f[x_] := 4 - g[4 - x]
g[x_ /; x > 4] := 8 + f[x - 8]
\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(16\)]\(f[2  m]\)\)

I tried the above method calculation but no results appeared.

(-1) This is at least 5th time you've asked about this type of problem (you've deleted the previous 4, though): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299614/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299613/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299612/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299605/1871 But still, you're mimicking blindly, I don't see your effort in understanding why the problem can be solved in those manners.

@xzczd I found the question fun but agree with underlying point you have expressed now and in other questions. I do not believe the edit of the question with a copy of a modified version of my code understands the approach…though it does achieve answer.  I only posted an answer from the general perspective of using MMA/WL for these sort of problems. I only really read the image inset that defined the problem.

No, the method with /; is fully applicable for the problem, if you've really understood it.

Oh, it's not 5th, it's 6th, I forgot this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299596/1871

If you're going to post the same question on another forum, you need to supply a link as otherwise you can be wasting the time of the experts trying to help you:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3164333.

On Version 14.0
p1 = f[x] + g[4 - x] == 4;
p2 = -f[x - 8] + g[x] == 8;
p3 = g[4] == 8;
p4 = g[4 - x] - g[x + 4] == 0;
p5 = p1 /. x -> 0;
Solve[{p5, p3}, {f[0], g[4]}]
p6 = p2 /. x -> x + 4
p7 = SubtractSides[SubtractSides[p1, p6], p4]
Fold[AddSides, 
 Table[p7 /. x -> j, {j, 6, 30, 8}]~Join~
  Table[p7 /. x -> j, {j, 8, 32, 8}]]


Comments:

I deleted my previous answer. Although it ran on my phone using Wolfram cloud, the answer I posted did not run on my laptop

This answer is to the original version of this question (as expressed in the image inset)

The values of the even values of f can be recovered (as in previous answer) but I see no point in posting that

I only post this for completeness



For the corrected code with values: here

Clear["`*"] p1 = f[x] + g[4 - x] == 4; p2 = -f[x - 8] + g[x] == 8; p3 = g[4] == 8; p4 = g[4 - x] - g[x + 4] == 0; Solve[{p1 /. x -> 0, p3}, {f[0], g[4]}] p5 = SubtractSides[SubtractSides[p1, p2 /. x -> x + 4], p4] q1 = f[x] /. RSolve[{p5, f[0] == -4}, f[x], x][[1]] f4 = Table[q1 /. x -> m, {m, 4, 32, 4}] Reduce[{p1 /. x -> -2, p2 /. x -> 6, p4 /. x -> 2,    p5 /. x -> 2}, {f[2], f[-2]}] p7 = f[x] /. RSolve[{p5, f[2] == -2}, f[x], x][[1]] f2 = Table[p7 /. x -> j, {j, 2, 30, 4}] Total[f2] + Total[f4]
